# Springboot Microservices Continuous Delivery With Docker And Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, microservices

I can't find any example or article how can the continuous delivery pipeline look like when we are using Spring Boot +Docker + Jenkins.

In our new project , We would like to deploy application as docker container in one of our VM’s . I written shell script for this in Jenkins and it's working fine.

The shell script has below steps

1. checkout branch from git
2. Zip the project folder
3. Move it to VM using SCP
4. Login to VM using ssh
5. Unzip the project folder
6. docker-compose stop
7. docker-compose build

But, I we would like to use Jenkins pipeline . Could anyone help with article or Jenkinsfile steps to achieve the same.

Thanks ,
Madhu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jenkins [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) to achive your goal.
Here is one sample example that will give you a little bit idea

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'some_build_node'
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Git Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }

        stage ('Build & Push Docker Image') {
            steps {
                // You can use this section to build and push image to registry 
            }
        }

        stage ('Deploy') {
            steps {
                    // Your steps to perform the deployment here
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
      always {
        // this block is to perform post build actions such as publishing the test report
        publishHTML target: [
            allowMissing: false,
            alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
            keepAll: true,
            reportDir: 'build/reports/tests/test',
            reportFiles: 'index.html',
            reportName: 'Junit Report'
          ]
      }
      success {
        // action you would want to do upon success. For example notifying about the build on slack/email
      }
      failure {
        // action you would want to do upon failure. For example notifying about the build on slack/email
      }
    }
}
```